# Unable to override CartPageMetaResolver

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to override the CartPageMetaResolver which looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BreadcrumbMeta,
    CmsService,
    PageBreadcrumbResolver,
    Priority,
    TranslationService } from '@spartacus/core';
import { CartPageMetaResolver } from '@spartacus/core/src/cart/services/cart-page-meta.resolver';
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NxsCartPageMetaResolver extends CartPageMetaResolver {}
```

While starting the server I am getting the following error

```
    ERROR in ./src/app/features/nxs-cart/services/nxs-cart-page-meta.resolver.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@spartacus/core/src/cart/services/cart-page-meta.resolver' 
in 'D:\HYBRIS_SPARTACUS\SPARTACUS\nexus\js-storefront\mystore\src\app\features\nxs-cart\services'
```

what might be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The `CartPageMetaResolver` is unfortunately not exported as part of the public API, it's a [bug](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/9976). We're fixing it, but you might want to unblock yourself by the following trick:

```
import { ɵct } from '@spartacus/core';
```

Note that the exact symbol for this class is different per release. This is why it's a temporary workaround, not something you want to keep. You can find the exact symbol in the `node_modules/@spartacus/core/spartacus-core.d.ts`.

We're fixing this for 3.0, but if you need a backport for 2.1, please let us know (we can continue the conversation in the ticket).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found a workaround for it for now.